# categorizing data in in to hash map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript object in the following format and I am trying to categorize it

```
var inputFacetArray=[
  { category:
"Company"
,  name:
"nokia"
},  { category:
"Persons"
,  name:
"ben affleck"
},  { category:
"Persons"
,  name:
"daniel craig"
},  { category:
"Persons"
,  name:
"george clooney"
}]
```

I am trying to get it in to the output format

```
[{Persons:["george clooney", "daniel craig", "ben affleck"]}, {company:["nokia"]}]
```

My code is following

```
var facetCategorizedArray=[];
for(var k=0; k<inputFacetArray.length; k++){
    var l={};
    inputFacetArray[k]["name"].push(l[inputFacetArray[k].category]);
    facetCategorizedArray.push(l);
}
```

above code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
var outputArray = {"Persons":[], "Company":[]};
for ( var counter = 0; counter < inputFacetArray.length; counter++ )
{
   outputArray.Persons.push( inputFacetArray[counter].category );
   outputArray.Company.push( inputFacetArray[counter].name );
}
```